# CSS3 overlay disappear when mouse goes out the browser window

Tags: css, overlay

I have one issue regarding overlay technique in CSS. I use :target element to display a div which have initially width:0 and height:0. But this new div disappear once I put my mouse out of the browser window.

You can check my code on that page, click on a thumbnail and move your mouse outside the browser window and see what happen:
http://wang-chang.com/test/photos/galerie-photos.html?aid=355194617939727

If anyone get any idea, it will be very appreciate :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which div are you talking about? the one with id mask?
you are only changing the opacity in hover

```
.view-sixth:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

found in

http://wang-chang.com/test/photos/css/style6.css

so when you move the mouse out, the opacity returns back to 0.